# How to use algorithmicx package?

Tags: errors, algorithms, algorithmicx

I found the `algorithmicx` package on [this page](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf), and tried to compile this example from the pdf file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
   \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
   \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex example.tex`, I got this error.

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment algorithm undefined.
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to remove

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

and use the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
```

The reason for this is because the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides (in addition to just defining the `algorithmic` environment through `algorithmicx.sty`) a bundle of style files with predefined macros (like `\Procedure`, `\Comment`, etc), including `algpseudocode.sty`. See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) (section **2.1 The package** for more on this).

One thing the `algorithmicx` package does *not* define is the floating `algorithm` environment. That is provided by the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms). Hence the requirement to include that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

and use the following in your header.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

I don't why. But what I do know is that the `algpseudocode` package don't work for me.

I'm using CTeX, hope this would help CTeX user. :P

Comment: `algpseudocode` defines the `algorithmic` environment - that's why. Why does `algpseudocode` not work for you?

Comment: Both didn't work for me. i am using winedit and elsevier.cls
Please how o get it right