# How to add white spaces (horizontally) in pseudocode

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to add some white spaces to my algorithm but without any progress. I did:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Example}
\begin{algorithmic}[2]
    \State Init:
        \State Example
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
```

what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you try following the example here? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/algorithms

Comment: I don't see the improvement, which I'm looking for because all (for, while ..etc) are reserved words that will give you directly the white space

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would help if you can modify your example to be a complete document, with the documentclass, packages, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Especially for pseudocode questions this is important, because there are various packages for creating pseudocode, and they interact with eachother, so it is necessary to know which (combination of) packages you use exactly.

Comment: thanks for you. the problem is I'm working on a very big document with a lot of dependencies and files and it's not possible to post all of these

Comment: You are not supposed to post the entire document, quite the opposite. We need code of a *small*, *complete* document that (1) illustrates your problem, and (2) shows us your context such that the solutions we propose will also work in your setting.

Comment: Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, I specified a new initialize block stucture for you as specified on [page 14](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)

[image: init]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}            %for math
\usepackage{amsfonts}           %American math society fonts
\usepackage{gensymb}            %Used for symbols such as $\degree$

\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithmicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\algblockdefx[initializeblock]{initialize}{endinitialize}%
   [1]{#1}%prints whatever you input
   {}%no end line

\caption{Example}
\begin{algorithmic}[2]
    \initialize{Init:}
        \State Example
    \endinitialize
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I noticed that the format for these kind of things tends to embolden the first line, you can do that by switching the block def statement to this ```\algblockdefx[initializeblock]{initialize}{endinitialize}%
   [1]{{\bfseries #1}}%prints whatever you input
   {}%no end line```

Comment: Also in case you havnt already found out, you have to initialize other packages to use algorithmicx. In fact for some reason it doesnt even look like you need ```\usepackage{algorithmicx}``` but it doesnt seem to hurt so I left it.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29429/how-to-use-algorithmicx-package